# Column ' column_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
    DevDate = CAST(a.allDates AS DATE), 
    FailsCount = COUNT(Test_Failure_Mode), 
    TotalCount = COUNT(*), 
    FailsRate = CAST(COUNT(Test_Failure_Mode) AS FLOAT)/ COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    A_Inspections a 
JOIN 
    B_Inspections b ON a.test_ID = b.test_ID 
WHERE 
    DevDate >= '2020-01-01' 
GROUP BY 
    DevDate
```

It looks like I am not accessing the tables properly and I am getting the following error:

> Column 'column_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: you can't use column alias in the `GROUP BY`. Change to the full expression `CAST(a.allDates AS DATE)`

Comment: Why are you casting `COUNT` as a float? If you are concerned about integer division then simply multiply by 1.0 or use a numeric datatype instead of float. Also, you have top 100 but no order by so you have no way of knowing which 100 rows you are going to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` an `alias` if it was created via a `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT top(100) 
      DevDate 
      FailsCount = COUNT(Test_Failure_Mode), 
      TotalCount = COUNT(*), 
      FailsRate = CAST(COUNT(Test_Failure_Mode) AS FLOAT)/ COUNT(*) 
 FROM A_Inspections a 
 JOIN  B_Inspections b ON a.test_ID = b.test_ID 
 CROSS APPLY ( values ( CAST(a.allDates AS DATE) ) ) V(DevDate)
 WHERE DevDate >= '2020-01-01' 
 GROUP BY DevDate
```

Or you can `GROUP BY` the expression

```
SELECT top(100) 
      DevDate    = CAST(a.allDates AS DATE)
      FailsCount = COUNT(Test_Failure_Mode), 
      TotalCount = COUNT(*), 
      FailsRate = CAST(COUNT(Test_Failure_Mode) AS FLOAT)/ COUNT(*) 
 FROM A_Inspections a 
 JOIN  B_Inspections b ON a.test_ID = b.test_ID 
 WHERE DevDate >= '2020-01-01' 
 GROUP BY CAST(a.allDates AS DATE)
```